# Error : 'The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 9(SIGKILL)' at training time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to train some Net using `ML-Engine`. My database has about ~40 000 images of cats and dogs together with bounding-boxes, for a size of `~6GB`. When I'm trying to launch the training, I have the following error :

```
ERROR   2018-08-14 12:05:57 +0200   service
  The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 9(SIGKILL).
  To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: (....)
```

I tried switching from `BASIC_GPU` config to `STANDARD_1`, but that doesn't change anything.

If I train of a smaller dataset, it works fine, but with this larger dataset, it will always terminate on this error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you reading in the data? Are you reading it all into memory?

Comment: I don't really know. My images are pickled into some file, then I call some function that read those very pickle. So yes, I guess I read them into the memory...

Comment: But yes, I basically load the all file into some numpy array. I think the solution would be to load it bit by bit, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading all of the data into RAM, you are running out of memory. The solution is to either get a bigger instance type (e.g. `large_model` or `complex_model_l`; see [docs for machine types](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/machine-types) for more details) or to not read the data all at once.

For the latter, see the docs on [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets). You may also refer to the [flowers sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers), which predates the tf.data API.

Answer (score 0):

‘Status 9’ error code occurs because of insufficient memory. The two options available are to move to a high memory machine, such as [large_model](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/machine-types#compare-machine-types) or reduce the dataset.